# pod failed to schedule on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kong, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following the instructions [here](https://getkong.org/install/kubernetes/?_ga=2.198602607.1524048868.1514090477-732856947.1514090477) to setup Kong on my Kubernetes cluster

At step 4, I issue the command:

```
$ kubectl create -f kong_migration_postgres.yaml

job "kong-migration" created
```

but I see this in my Google container engine:

[image]

What is causing the issue?  Do I need to increase the size of my cluster?

Comment: can you paste what's in Events? also can you show details about your cluster? it's not clear if you don't have enough capacity or if there's another issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the cluster did not have enough CPU capacity.  The error is visible if you click on the pod (at the very bottom of the dashboard) and you'll then see the error.  Increasing the size of the cluster or turning on auto-scaling will fix it.